# Output nested array properly

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I try to build a data tree in Vue, using components.

Consider the following data:

```
"data": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "foo",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "bar",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "hulu",
      "children": []
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "foobar",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "foobar hulu",
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}]
```

Now i want to output it with a table like:

ID ║    Name     ║        Path         
 1 ║ foo         ║ /foo                
 2 ║ bar         ║ /foo/bar            
 3 ║ hulu        ║ /foo/hulu           
 4 ║ foobar      ║ /foobar             
 5 ║ foobar hulu ║ /foobar/foobar hulu

I've tried using a component that "calls" itself if there are children available. The problem is that Vue.js only allows one root element.

My components:

```
var Element = {
    props: ['context', 'path'],
    name: 'self',
    template: `
        <tr>
            <td>{{context.id}}</td>
            <td>{{context.name}}</td>
            <td>{{path}}</td>
        </tr>
        <self v-if="context.children.length != 0" v-for="child in context.children" :context="child" :path="path + '/' + child.name"></self>
    `
};

var Tree = {
    components: {
        'element': Element
    },
    template: `
        <table v-if="elements.length != 0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Path</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <element v-for="element in elements" :context="element" :path="'/' + element.name"></element>
        </table>
    `,
```

How would you bypass this problem? I've tried wrapping the element template inside a **tbody**. This will calculate the path correctly and outputs all elements, however that would produce rows that are nested inside columns and looks really ugly.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flatten the paths.

```
Vue.component("flat-tree",{
  props:["paths"],
  template: "#flat-tree-template",
  methods:{
    flatten(data, root, accumulator){
      return data.reduce((acc, val) => {
        accumulator.push({
          id: val.id,
          name: val.name,
          path: root + val.name
        });
        if (val.children)
          return this.flatten(val.children, root + val.name + "/", accumulator);
        else
          return accumulator;
      }, accumulator);
    }
  },
  computed:{
    flattened(){
      return this.flatten(this.paths, "/", []);
    }
  }
})
```

Template

```
<template id="flat-tree-template">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="path in flattened">
      <td>{{path.id}}</td>
      <td>{{path.name}}</td>
      <td>{{path.path}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>
```

[Working example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/KWpRaW?editors=1010).

Comment: Great! Unfortunately your codepen does not work, but i figured it out myself. Why are you using a computed property to output the data? Isn't v-for="flatten(paths, '/', [])" the same?

Comment: @Qobus I was playing with the codepen for a little while, so it's possible you clicked the link when it was in a bad state; apologies. It should be working now. I'm using a computed property because the flattened paths are derived from the original paths. By using a computed, if the original paths change, the flattened paths will be recomputed and reflect the new state.

Comment: @Qobus generally it just looks cleaner, at least to me. You are correct, v-for="path in flatten(paths, '/', [])" would accomplish pretty much the same thing.